# Restful WCF POST issue with application/json content type request

Tags: json, wcf, post, wcf-rest, bad-request

I've configured a RESTful WCF with the following POST "operation":

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/Test", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
void PostTest(Stream stream);
```

In my web.config, I've configured the following:

```
<service name="MyTest.TestSvc" behaviorConfiguration="MyTest.TestBehavior" >
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyTest.ITestSvc"/>
     <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
</service>

<endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyBehavior">
        <webHttp />
    </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyTest.TestBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

When I sent a POST message using **"text/plain"** or **"json"** everything works fine.
However, when I try to send a POST message with
**ContentType = "application/json"**
It fails with the following message:
**The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request**

The only solution which I found was to define the Factory class : **System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebServiceHostFactory** int the Svc definition markup.

I found this solution in the following link:
[Send JSON to WCF 3.5 using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6617387/send-json-to-wcf-3-5-using-ajax)

As I understood , defining the WebServiceHostFactory is only useful if you don't want to edit the web.config.

How can I make it work without defining the WebServiceHostFactory?

Notice that I succeed to get "json" content type POST message but not "application/json" content type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that to use the raw programming model (using a `Stream` parameter), you'll need to tell WCF to not try to understand the request as JSON, instead just pass the raw request body to the parameter. You can do that using a `WebContentTypeMapper`. The post at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2008/04/17/wcf-raw-programming-model-receiving-arbitrary-data.aspx shows how this can be done. The solution with the factory works because it does that when it creates the endpoint.