# WCF Rest service - passing XML with POST

Tags: xml, wcf, rest, post, content-type

I've inherited an ASPX page which is POSTed to by a client. I can't change the client. I want to redo this as a WCF Rest service. The ASPX page retrieves XML data from the request in the Page_load event

After a good bit of reading I have a WCF Rest service setup which works with the same test data, but only if my test code sets the contentType to:

```
  request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencode";
```

The client calling me will just be using:

```
  request.ContentType = @"text/xml";
```

and this fails with a **400 error**.

Here's my interface:

```
public interface ISmsReceive {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare,
    UriTemplate = "xml")]
    string Receive(Stream ID);
}
```

and here's a sample call which works:

```
  string s = "http://localhost:1773/SmsReceive.svc/xml";
  String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "<accountrequest>" + // xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" +
            "<accountprocessinboundmessage>" +
            "<inboundnumber><![CDATA[123]]></inboundnumber>" +
            "<dateinsert><![CDATA[1/1/2003 12:00:00 PM]]></dateinsert>" +
            "<inboundcli><![CDATA[+123]]></inboundcli>" +
            "<message><![CDATA[blah blah]]></message>" +
            "</accountprocessinboundmessage>" +
            "</accountrequest>";

  WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(s);

  request.Method = "POST";
  // Works with this
  request.ContentType = @"application/x-www-form-urlencode";

  // Fails with this
  //request.ContentType = @"text/xml";

  xmlStream = (request.GetRequestStream());
  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(xmlStream);
  writer.Write(xmlString);
  writer.Flush();
  writer.Close();

  WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
  String responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

I read in one post that you must define an xmlns in the XML - but even with code above uncommented which inserts this it still fails.

Cheers for any pointers,

Ray

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840519/restful-wcf-post-issue-with-application-json-content-type-request

Comment: Jocke - that pointed me in the right direction and I'm all st now. Thanks for that. For anyone else interested in this, this shows how to set the binding in the config: http://vivekcek.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/wcf-rest-service-accepting-raw-xml-webcontenttypemapper/